# Error Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll could not be found

Tags: .net-5

I am getting error like :-

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer\5.0.3\lib\net5.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.data.sqlite.core\5.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.dotnet.platformabstractions\3.1.6\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore\5.0.10\lib\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.abstractions\5.0.10\lib\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational\5.0.10\lib\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlite.core\5.0.3\lib\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\5.0.2\lib\net5.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencymodel\5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens\6.8.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.logging\6.8.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols\6.7.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect\6.7.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.tokens\6.8.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.openapi\1.2.3\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.OpenApi.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.bundle_e_sqlite3\2.0.4\lib\netcoreapp3.1\SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.bundle_e_sqlite3\2.0.4\lib\netcoreapp3.1\SQLitePCLRaw.nativelibrary.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.core\2.0.4\lib\netstandard2.0\SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.provider.dynamic_cdecl\2.0.4\lib\netstandard2.0\SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swagger\5.6.3\lib\netcoreapp3.0\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swaggergen\5.6.3\lib\netcoreapp3.0\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swaggerui\5.6.3\lib\netcoreapp3.0\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\system.collections.immutable\5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Collections.Immutable.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\system.componentmodel.annotations\5.0.0\ref\netstandard2.1\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource\5.0.1\lib\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3106: Assembly strong name "C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt\6.8.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(). Those characters are Equals(=), Comma(,), Quote("), Apostrophe('), Backslash(). [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Users\MANAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers\5.0.10\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\MANAS\Downloads\API\API.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

Comment: 14 Views...and nobody knows this error ??? wah

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar error in VS Code, I updated my VS 2019 to the latest version which currently is 16.11.

That fixed the error for me.